# Self hosted SignalR client method not invoked

Tags: angularjs, signalr

I know this issue has been treated before since I have googled and read most of the responses of people who have had the same or similar problem in the past. None of them have been the solution for my case. The problem I have is my client method is not getting called and I have already defined the client method before starting the hub. When I do that I get another error but when I define the method after starting my hub, I don't get an error but then my client function does not get fired.

I think, the fact that I am self-hosting in a Win service using static files serving or because I am using AngularJS, that's why I am having this problem. but I am not really sure.

Can you help me? Any suggestions? Of course I have gone through the SignalR troubleshooting guide several times. I have checked the name of my client method to make sure all is correctly named but still this problems rears it head. I would like to believe the fact that its because I am self hosting or because of Angular . I know that when I define my client method before starting the hub, the hub tries to setup subscriptions to the signal service and when it tries to do so fails because it cannot find (my assumption) the hub which is defined (Hub name: OffiHub) in a folder (/OffiSignalR/Hubs).

I get the following error when I debug using Chrome: jquery-2.2.1.js:9175 GET http://localhost:36900/OffiG/start?transport=serverSentEvents&clientPD%3D&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22offihub%22%7D%5D&_=1459195567970 500 (Internal Server Error)

In case you wish to see my code, here it is:

```
var offiHub = $.connection.offiHub;
offiHub.client.publishSales = function (so) {
//Add to the current list.
console.log("We got here!");
log('We got here, hurray!.');
};

$.connection.hub.start().done(init);
```

Comment: turn on detailed errors in your hub configuration and see if there is something more there. You can check how to that here: [hub options](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-server#options)

Comment: I have already done that, both on the server and the client. All I get is the above posted error message.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer to my problem. It was all my fault, I had a code snippet in the OnConnected method on the server which was failing when I try to connect to the service from the client. I had placed the code there for when I would need it but hadn't thought much about it. This code has given me much grief these past few days. Remove it and all is working well from all clients. In fact it was the .Net client that made me suspect the faulty code.